# Magit log: move cursor to the HEAD

Tags: magit

While in the log buffer, is there a way to move the cursor directly to the HEAD commit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.

If you wish to implement such a command, then I would recommend searching for the respective (abbreviated) hash in the buffer and moving there.

Comment: Sometimes HEAD is not visible, and sometimes it's not even an ancestor of the commit displayed, so maybe I should just stick to using `magit-log-current`. Thanks anyway!